# Property of convolution product for $e^{\frac{x^2}{2t}}$

Tags: integration, stochastic-processes, convolution

Let $g_t(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi t}} e^{-\frac{x^2}{2t}}$, in some probability (stochastic processes) papers and exercises I saw that this function satisfies the (very useful) property: 
$$ (g_t * g_s)(x)=g_{t+s}(x) $$

Writing down the integrals, this is equivalent to:

$$ \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi(t+s)}}e^{-\frac{x^2}{2(t+s)}}=\int_{\mathbb{R}} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi t}}e^{-\frac{(x-y)^2}{2t}} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi s}}e^{-\frac{y^2}{2s}} \, dy $$

I tried out various basic substitutions with various coefficients (like $y\sqrt{t+s}=u$) and also tried to write something as an integral and then switch integration order (Fubini-Tonelli), but I couldn't turn it into a form I can handle yet. May someone give me some hints? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that by completing the square we have

$$\begin{align}
\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi t}}e^{-\frac{(x-y)^2}{2t}} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi s}}e^{-\frac{y^2}{2s}} \, dy&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{4\pi^2st}}\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-\frac1{2st}\left(s(x-y)^2+ty^2\right)}\,dy\\\\
&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{4\pi^2st}}\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-\frac1{2st}\left((s+t)\left(y-\frac{sx}{s+t}\right)^2+\frac{st}{s+t}x^2\right)}\,dy\\\\
&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{4\pi^2st}}e^{-\frac{x^2}{s+t}}\underbrace{\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-\frac{s+t}{2st}y^2}\,dy }_{=\sqrt{\frac{\pi(2st)}{s+t}}}\\\\
&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi(s+t)}}\,e^{-\frac{x^2}{s+t}}
\end{align}$$

as was to be shown!

Comment: I can't believe..tried out circus substitutions while it was just some clear algebra. Kind of overestimated it. By the way, fast and neat solution, thank you :)

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure.   -Mark

Answer (score 1):

Do some algebra including completing the square:
$$
\frac{(x-y)^2}{2t} + \frac{y^2}{2s} = \frac{(y-[{\cdots}])^2}{2(\cdots)}.
$$

If you have $\displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-(y-[\cdots])^2/(2[\cdots])} \, dy,$ what do you get?